# Resizing iFrame with jQuery UI

Tags: jquery, iframe, user-interface, resize

I have this code and it works fine:

Head

```
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        $("#test").resizable({minHeight: 50, minWidth: 50});
    });
</script>
```

Body

```
<div id="test" style="border: .1em solid black;">
</div>
```

However when I change my "div" into "iframe" I can't resize it anymore.

Body

```
<iframe id="test" style="border: .1em solid black;">
</iframe>
```

Comment: Here an answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13473569/676479

Answer (score 15):

Found redsquare's demo a bit wonky when moving the mouse more than a few pixels at a time.  I've applied a couple modifications that help make resizing a lot smoother:

```
<html>
<head>
  <style type="text/css"> 
    #resizable { width: 150px; height: 150px; padding: 0.5em; }
    #resizable h3 { text-align: center; margin: 0; }
    .ui-resizable-helper { border: 75px solid #EFEFEF; margin: -75px; }
  </style> 
  <script type="text/javascript"> 
    $(function() {
      $("#resizable").resizable({
        helper: "ui-resizable-helper"
      });
    });
  </script> 
</head> 
<body> 
  <div class="demo"> 
    <div id="resizable" class="ui-widget-content"> 
      <iframe src="http://pastebin.me/f9ed9b9d36d17a7987e9cb670e01f0e2" class="ui-widget-content" frameborder="no" id="test" width="100%" height="100%" />
    </div> 
  <div>
</body>
</html>
```

The weirdness of resizing seems to happen because mousemove events don't bubble up from within the iframe.  Using a resize handler and a large border in the handler CSS minimizes the effect caused by the iframe as long as the browser can keep up with the mousemove events.

Comment: Thanks for sharing how to fix the choppy resize with iframes, it was driving me crazy! :)

Comment: An alternative fix for the choppy resize is to add the `iframeFix` patch posted [here](http://bugs.jqueryui.com/attachment/ticket/4903/jquery.ui.resizable-iframeFix.patch). It prevents iframes from capturing the mouse during a resize.

Answer (score 13):

Below Code Work for me in smooth way.

```
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>jQuery UI Resizable - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>

  <style>

  #iframe {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: none;    

  background: #eee ;


  z-index: 1;
}

#resizable {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;


  z-index: 9;
}
  </style>
  <script>
  $(function() {
    $('#resizable').resizable({
      start: function(event, ui) {
        $('iframe').css('pointer-events','none');
         },
    stop: function(event, ui) {
        $('iframe').css('pointer-events','auto');
      }
  });
  });
  </script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="resizable">
  <iframe src="test.html" id="iframe">

</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks your code working in 2023 also :D

Answer (score 1):

I think this might be what you are looking for: Place the content of whatever is in your iframe in a div. For this example I will give the div an id of "container".

```
$('#ID_iframe').css("height", "" + $('#ID_iframe').contents().find("#container").height() + "px");
```

Answer (score 1):

I landed up here for searchin `Resize iframe`, But this question is about resizing using Jquery UI plugin, I am just adding a answer so it might be helpful for someone in future who falls into this page searching to resize iframe.
This can be done using only CSS

```
iframe {
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  resize: both;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

Also all the major browsers have good support. [Check out this link](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/r/resize/) and also about the [browser support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-resize)