# Make IFrames resizable dynamically

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, html-table

I have the following HTML page in which I have three iframes. I would like to allow users to resize the height and width of the iframes manually using Javascript.

```
<body>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2" id = "freebase_td">
        <iframe id = "freebase_frame" src="" width="100%" height="400px"></iframe>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="left" id = "wiki_td">
        <iframe id = "wiki_frame" src="" width="100%" height="400px"></iframe>
        </td>
        <td align="right" id = "imdb_td">
        <iframe id = "imdb_frame" src="" width="100%" height="400px"></iframe>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your best bet really is to use a library to do this, such as [jQueryUI Resizable](http://jqueryui.com/demos/resizable/) -- there are a lot of inter-browser quirks with doing this right. Especially when you need to allow the user to specify an arbitrary size/resize, and a draggable resize handle is almost always the most intuitive way to allow users to resize an element. Setting the width/height of the iframe directly should be okay if you are just resizing the iframe, but that doesn't do anything to get the new width/height from the user in an intuitive way.

Also see [Resizing iFrame with jQuery UI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1234144/resizing-iframe-with-jquery-ui) -- you need to wrap the iframe in a div, set the iframe to height=100% width=100%, and make the div resizable. Drag-to-resize will not work correctly if you make the bare iframe Draggable. (This is an event bubbling limitation in some browsers, not a jQuery bug per se.)

Answer (score 2):

you don't need javascript for that in modern browsers. just a little html+css trick. encapsulate your iframe in a div with resize property enabled.

```
<div>
  <iframe src="https://www.example.com/"></iframe>
</div>

<style>
div {
  overflow: hidden;
  resize: both;
}
iframe {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
}
</style>
```

demo: https://jsfiddle.net/k53a41ej/

Comment: scrolling seems to be in the way

Answer (score 1):

I choose to avoid iFrames like a curse.  I know this isnt exaclty what you asked for but check out [jQueryUI's Resizable](http://jqueryui.com/demos/resizable/).

If you change your foundational structure you might find this a much more scalable/long term solution.

**Note: Resizable can be applied to ANY DOM element!**

Answer (score 0):

Does this not work?

```
document.getElementById('wiki_frame').style.width = '300px';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function(){
    $("table td").css({position:'relative'})
    $("div.resizer").appendTo($("table td")).each(function(){

     $(this).width(20);
     $(this).height(20);
     $(this).css({
          position:"absolute",
          top: $(this).parent().height() - 20,
          left: $(this).parent().width() - 20
     });
     var resize = false;
     var $td;
     var pos;
     $(this).mousedown(function(e){resize = true;$td =$(this).parent(); pos = {left:e.pageX,top:e.pageY});});
      $(document).mousemove(function(e){

           if( resize ){
                  $td.height( $td.height() + e.pageY - pos.top );
                  $td.width( $td.width() + e.pageX- pos.left);
            }
       });
       $(document).mouseup(function(){

            resize = false;
      });
    });
})();
```