# User Manipulated Frame - HTML/CSS/JS

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

How can I make the below frame, once loaded, to allow for the user to drag and scale the size? Is this possible with HTML/CSS/JS?

```
<script>
    var frame;
    function addFrame() {
       frame = document.createElement('iframe');
       frame.height = "200px";
       frame.width = "200px";
       frame.setAttribute('id', 'superFrame');
       document.body.appendChild(frame);
    }
    function loadGoogle() {
       frame.setAttribute('src','http://www.google.com')
    }
</script>
```

Left is what I have, right is what I want but with the user setting the size via dragging the frame.

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iWWkH.png)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6194302/how-can-i-cleanly-resize-an-iframe-with-dragging-functionality

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8117761/how-can-i-make-an-iframe-resizable

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7816372/make-iframes-resizable-dynamically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

src [Responsive IFrames — The Right Way!](https://benmarshall.me/responsive-iframes/)

1. remove width and height attributes
2. set up a parent div for the iframe
3. make the containing div responsive, and the iframe with the following size/positioning rules:

   iframe {
     position: absolute;
     top:0;
     left: 0;
     width: 100%;
     height: 100%;
   }