# Resize all children elements in iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Resizing iFrame with jQuery UI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1234144/resizing-iframe-with-jquery-ui)

I need to embed an iframe. I would like all the elements in the iframe to dynamically resize while setting the size of the iframe.
Is there a way doing it in Jquery? Other suggestions ?

Comment: Do you have any control over the contents of the iframe?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1234144/resizing-iframe-with-jquery-ui

Comment: PhonicUK - I've got control of the elements, i generate the content.
I want it to act like flash , when you resize the parent element it would resize everything inside.

Comment: Within the frame use [viewport size](http://andylangton.co.uk/articles/javascript/get-viewport-size-javascript/) or relative CSS sizes (e.g. `width: 30%;`) so as the iFrame changes in size the content recognizes the viewport size has changed and accommodates.