# Jquery UI resizable - resize a div placed over an iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui

If you check out this jsbin: http://jsbin.com/efosed/5/edit and you press "Run with JS", there will be a div that can be resized with jquery ui. Everything works like expected.
The div is placed over a "full-screen" iframe. In the linked example this iframe has: `display: none`.

If I modify it to `display: block`, and re-run the script the reziable plugin will have some strange behavior. You can try it here: http://jsbin.com/efosed/6/edit.
It will not handle mouse events correctly.
What can be the reason, and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You have to implement your own logic to fix iframe. One solution is to add a div over your iframe:

[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/apaxij/98/edit)

```
$(function() {
  $('#resizable').resizable({
      start: function(event, ui) {
        $('<div class="ui-resizable-iframeFix" style="background: #fff;"></div>')
            .css({
                width:'100%', height: '100%',
                position: "absolute", opacity: "0.001", zIndex: 1000
           })
            .appendTo("body");
      },
    stop: function(event, ui) {
        $('.ui-resizable-iframeFix').remove()
      }
  });
});
```

For [modern browsers](http://caniuse.com/pointer-events) which support CSS property `pointer-events`, there is a better solution, see code and jsbin:

[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/apaxij/100/edit)

```
$(function() {
  $('#resizable').resizable({
      start: function(event, ui) {
        $('iframe').css('pointer-events','none');
         },
    stop: function(event, ui) {
        $('iframe').css('pointer-events','auto');
      }
  });
});
```

Comment: You can do this without js on newer browsers. `.ui-resizable-resizing iframe{ pointer-events:none;}`

Comment: @epelc But the iframe isn't descendant of resizable element in this example, otherwise i guess it would work

Comment: @A.Wolff missed that one. You are right. Also I'm even more wrong because there is a bug with mine if you have a grid. If there are iframes next to something you are resizing they can break your events too.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it even simpler:

Javascript

```
$(function() {
  $('#resizable').resizable({
      start: function(event, ui) {
        $(this).addClass('freeze')
      },
    stop: function(event, ui) {
        $(this).removeClass('freeze')
      }
  });
});
```

CSS

```
#resizable.freeze iframe { pointer-events: none; }
```

Comment: well jQuery already adds a class (ui-resizable-resizing), no real need of your own, thus no need to add 2 callbacks.

Answer (score 0):

CSS only method

.ui-resizable-resizing iframe {
    pointer-events: none;
}

The `ui-resizable-resizing` class is added whenever you are resizing something.