# Is there a way to make an iframe's height expandable without a scrollbar?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

So that it pushes down and then pushes up the content that comes after the closing tag?

For example, I made this info-graphic and it has a share button; we want that button to open a box with the code that someone will copy and paste on their own pages. The info-graphic needs to be sort of like a mirror, so that when someone posts it on the page another person can see it and share it on their own page as well and so on.

My solution to this problem was to use an iframe, it will display:

http://andressa-casale.com.br/NV/page_01.html

This page wich alread has the share button. The problem is the only way I got it to work is by putting a fixed height on the iframe tag. This causes a blank space between the contracted share box and the text comes after the tag .

http://justaplacetoposttests.blogspot.com.br/

Since I have no control over the text that will come after the tag, I need to work with the iframe, make its height expandable when it opens and closes the share box.

Is that even possible? If there is a simpler way to do that can somebody help me?

This is the iframe I built:

```
<iframe style="padding: 0px; width: 100%; height: 965px;" src="http://andressa-casale.com.br/NV/page_01.html" align="left" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>
```

Comment: [See this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1234144/resizing-iframe-with-jquery-ui)

Comment: @fnostro It hasn't worked, I don't think it's the same problem. I need to creat an iframe that lots of people will copy and post on their own pages. I can't ask them to save the javascript in their sites. See the example here: http://justaplacetoposttests.blogspot.com.br/

Comment: If people are posting this iframe code on their site, you have no control over it, besides the content that gets put in it, if the content that gets put in it is coming from a site that you manage.  So, in short, they can change the height/width of the iframe as they see fit, and you will not be able to control it.  You can only control the content within the iframe itself...  Perhaps, what you need is an iframe within an iframe?  Than you give them the code for the HTML to use for their iframe that actually has another iframe inside of it.

Comment: @SolomonClosson thanks, indeed there's no way to control what the person will do with the code once they put in their site. But my issue is not with them changing the height. What I need is to make the iframe _move_ the content that comes after it (not inside) because my contet has a javascript that changes the height once you click the button. Please, click on this link: http://justaplacetoposttests.blogspot.com.br/ You'll get a better understanding of what I need to do. Which is to get rid of the blank space that is there to fit my content once the button is clicked. Thank you

Comment: @user3220690 - This is not possible because of the Same-origin policy that exists on iframes.  You can not control any elements that do not exist within your iframe: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript

Comment: @SolomonClosson thank you for your help, that's too bad I can't fix the blank space. :/